# Replacing HTML-Elements on form submit

Tags: javascript

With a button click I generate a PDF, which is then sent to server and a response comes back, if the POST-Request was successfull. While generating the pdf and waiting for response, I want button to have a spinner and be disabled. Here are 2 buttons:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;">Submit</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style= "visibility: hidden;" id="btn-loading" disabled>
  <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   Loading...
</button>
```

I generate pdf with:

```
function printPDF (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
.......

}
```

Inside of `printPDF (e)` I first prove the required fields and only afterwards generate the pdf.

```
e.preventDefault();

if (!eimailInput.checkValidity()) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('warning-paragraph')[2].style.display = 'block';

} else if (!checkboxData.checkValidity()) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('warning-paragraph')[1].style.display = 'block';

} else if (( checkPriceOutputs() == false )) {

  document.getElementsByClassName('warning-paragraph')[0].style.display = 'block';

} else { let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210], true);}...
```

For now the working version was:

```
button.addEventListener('click', printPDF)
```

Now if required fields are fine, basically where the else happens, I need to switch my buttons.

```
document.getElementById('btn-submit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('btn-loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

As some comments suggest below, I moved the logic into else-section of printPDF(), but no switch happens here.

```
... } else {
      document.getElementById('btn-submit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('btn-loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
      let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210], true);} ...
```

Apart from that, buttons are not rendered on the same position, so you definetely see the 'jump' between two buttons.

Comment: Change `type="submit" ` to `type="button"` and move `replaceButton();` into printPdf and still use addEventListener instead of inline code

Comment: Try with `document.getElementById('btn-submit').style.display= 'none';` and 
`document.getElementById('btn-loading').style.display= 'block';` with this button should be rendered at same position

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange

```
function replaceAndPrint(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('btn-submit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('btn-loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
  printPDF()
};

button.addEventListener('click', replaceAndPrint)
```

Also

Change `type="submit"`  to `type="button"` to not need `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: So, without `preventDefault` button only switches after response comes from server... With `preventDefault`in both printPDF(e) and replaceAndPrint(e), the switch happens, but no request is being sent. I did change the type to button.

Comment: Oh, I know, reponse is part of printPDF()! I probaly need to edit the question

Answer (score -1):

Typically, if you want to have more things to be done while you click on any button irrespective of a normal button or submit type, the best way is to have one function call on button click and do all that you want in that function.
For Example

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>
<script> 
function fnOnSubmit()
{
  
  document.getElementById("btnSubmit").value = "loading...";
  document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = "disabled";
  //fnDowork1();
  //fnDowork2();

  //pdf Generation logic
  // If this is through some kind of API then once the response has come, 
  // maybe enable the button and change the text
  //Return true will submit the page, false will prevent the page
  return false;
}
</script>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return fnOnSubmit()" id="btnSubmit" >  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick="return fnOnSubmit()"` if you want return false to stop the page from reloading

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid

Comment: Also if you want a submit button to do the job, wrap in a form and use the submit event instead of the click event and don't use inline events

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. The point I was trying to say is if we want to do many things, encapsulate them in a function.